# Pagina web en blanco

Tags: html, linux, emacs

Buen dia 
No se por que mi pagina web sale en blanco
alguien me podria ayudar a revisar el codigo
gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, trata de postear el código y no las fotos. Te sugiero que leas [¿Cómo elaboro un buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Luego reformula la pregunta para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Buen dia gracias por los concejos

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Compañero, no logro leer muy bien, pero creo que es en esta parte.

Tienes tu codigo arriba del body así:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
```

Y no cerraste tu style.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen"></style>
```

Prueba eso.